# Incorrect page number for LoA in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I want to create a list of appendices at the end of my document, and add the corresponding entry and page number to the table of contents.

The following code is a simplified version of my code (MWE), with dummy text applied.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter   % start of 
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{Anhangsverzeichnis}
\newlistof{appendix}{apc}{\listappendixname}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhangsverzeichnis}
    \write\@auxout{%
        \string\let\string\latex@tf@toc\string\tf@toc% 
        \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@apc% 
    }
}
\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \write\@auxout{%
        \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\latex@tf@toc% 
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%\nopagebreakchapter{bla bla}
\chapter{bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\section{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\chapter{bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\section{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2-3]

% #############################################################################


\clearpage
\listofappendix

\begin{appendices}

\section{questions}
\lipsum[1]

\section{answers}
\lipsum[1]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

In this example I expect the page number for the LoA to be `4`, not `5` (assuming you use the parameter `a4paper` for the `report` class). It seems to me that LaTeX is always selecting the page for the first chapter of the appendix. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhangsverzeichnis}` from `\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{...}` and add

```
\preto{\cftafterapctitle}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendixname}%
}
```

to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter   % start of 
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{Anhangsverzeichnis}
\newlistof{appendix}{apc}{\listappendixname}
\preto{\cftafterapctitle}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendixname}%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \clearpage
    \write\@auxout{%
        \string\let\string\latex@tf@toc\string\tf@toc% 
        \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@apc% 
    }
}
\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \write\@auxout{%
        \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\latex@tf@toc% 
    }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{bla bla}
\lipsum[1]
\section{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[3-7]

\clearpage
\listofappendix
\begin{appendices}
\section{questions}
\lipsum[1]
\section{answers}
\lipsum[2]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

---

If you are option `titles` is used for package `tocloft` you have to patch  `\listofappendix` to get a TOC entry for the LOA:

```
\patchcmd\listofappendix
  {\chapter*{\listappendixname}}
  {\chapter*{\listappendixname}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendixname}}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
```

If it should work with and without option `titles` use

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newcommand{\listappendixname}{Anhangsverzeichnis}
\newlistof{appendix}{apc}{\listappendixname}

\makeatletter
\if@cftnctoc% with option titles
  \patchcmd\listofappendix
    {\chapter*{\listappendixname}}
    {\chapter*{\listappendixname}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendixname}}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}
\else% without option titles
  \preto{\cftafterapctitle}{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendixname}%
  }
\fi

\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \clearpage
    \write\@auxout{%
        \string\let\string\latex@tf@toc\string\tf@toc% 
        \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@apc% 
    }
}
\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \write\@auxout{%
        \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\latex@tf@toc% 
    }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{bla bla}
\lipsum[1]
\section{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{bla bla bla}
\lipsum[3-7]

\clearpage
\listofappendix
\begin{appendices}
\section{questions}
\lipsum[1]
\section{answers}
\lipsum[2]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. One small question still comes to my mind though. I need to alter the prefix for elements in LoT and LoF, but for this I need to add the `titles` parameter to the `tocloft` package. If I do so the entry for the LoA gets removed from the LoT. What can I do here?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: If I could I would give u multiple upvotes for your great help. Everything works as expected.